# What do PerfPowerService and PerfPowerTelemetryService do?

Tags: malware, macos

Anyone have any idea what the PerfPowerService and PerfPowerTelemetry...Service is on macOS (Sonoma?) I can't seem to find a lot of information on these processes. The second one isn't even mentioned in the Unix man pages.

Is there any accessible list of legit macOS processes (pure macOS/default Unix processes that is)?

Comment: Found that for PerfPowerService, it looks like it's related to Screen/Energy Saver: https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/PerfPowerServices.8.html

Comment: Alright! PerfPowerService seems fine, but the other process is not documented at all :/. Do you have that one too (on your Mac if you're using one)? I assume it's relatively new, maybe introduced with Sonoma. I'd love for Apple to document processes like these some more.

Comment: These are located in usr/libexec which is a folder for programs that are used by other programs. According to [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102149) it should be SIP protected.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I just wanted to know what they do and whether they are legit (I was mostly concerned about the telemetry one though).

Comment: The second one is actually a Private Framework for the Power Log, found here: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/PerfPowerTelemetryClientRegistrationService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/PerfPowerTelemetryClientRegistrationService

Comment: @Redarm Thank you very much!